# How to print Acrobat PDF file without the images

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, printing

I have a image-heavy PDF file and want to print part of it. Is there a way to print it without the images, but preserving the file layout (Save as Text is not an option, because it breaks the layout).

I've found one software that can convert it (Coherent PDF), but it is too expensive for a one time task like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a copy of Acrobat Professional, it normally comes with the "Adobe LiveCycle Designer" software. Here you can import your PDF into an "Interactive Form with Flowable Layout". It will try to break apart your PDF into the base components and allow you to rip out the pictures while still keeping the general format.

From what I can tell, editing PDF's takes a paid app. Though I wonder if you can use the trial software on the Adobe website to get a single print off. I'm not quite sure what the limitations of that software is, but it might be worth a try.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Mac, you can use Preview (for free!) to draw a white box on the images you don't want to be printed, so the rest of the layout stays the same. Remember to make sure that the box is filled in with white color and the lines around it are invisible (or also in white).

Steps:

1. Open your PDF file in Preview.
2. Make sure the "Markup Toolbar" is
   shown. You can show/hide this toolbar by pressing Command+Shift+A.
3. Using the fourth item from left in the Markup Toolbar, you can draw rectangles or circles as you need.
4. The second and third item from right in the Markup Toolbar can be used to choose the color of the filling and border, respectively.

If you want to print only part of your PDF, you can choose to show thumbnails from View menu, and select the pages that you want to print.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) needs to be improved. For example, please provide step-by-step instructions to implement your answer and explain how it addresses the OPs question for those who may not understand what you're getting at.

Comment: updated. See if you want to change your score!! :)

Comment: Good edits. The down vote wasn't mine, but I upvoted your improved answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the free online converter at http://www.freepdftoword.org/ and choose the Remove Images option at Step 2.

This does not "print" the document but gets you a version of it in Word that preserves the layout but removes the images.

Answer (score 1):

No apps or utilities required! To print a PDF file without images, try the following:

1. In Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro, in the **File** menu, click **Export**, and then click **Word Document**
2. In the **Save As** window, name and save the file
3. Open Microsoft Word 2010, and then open the newly-named file
4. In Word, remove any images you don't want to print
5. Print the Word document

Comment: No apps or utilities required? What exactly are Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro and Microsoft Word 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You could download the [**pdfToolbox4**](http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en:products:pdftoolbox4) from callassoftware.com. It's a commercial tool, and it is not cheap. But they give you a 14 day evaluation license, so it should be good for getting your one-time task done.

pdfToolbox has many, many features and functions to manipulate PDFs. The one you want to use is: put images and non-images on different layers. Once you've done that, enable printing only for the non-image layer. Or delete the image layer altogether and save it as a new PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a text box on images and set the background and border color to white,then print.

Comment: How would you draw a text box over the images? Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: This is actually the best and clever answer... No expensive third party tools. I just did it with Foxit Pdf reader. Idea is to add a comment above the images

Answer (score 0):

If your PDF is organized into layers when it was created, then this may work:

1. Open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader
2. Click View -> Show/Hide -> Navigation Panes -> Layers
3. On the left pane, from the bottom up, check off (i.e. hide) layer names that suggest they have background images (e.g. background images, images, background, watermark etc.)

i learned this technique from here:
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/print-pdf-background-57017.html

Answer (score -2):

Very simple. Just copy that file and paste in the Microsoft word. Then delete the images in the Microsoft word and print out.

Comment: Only certain versions of Word support importing a PDF document, even then, the formatting isn't perfect.  It would be easier to just edit the PDF file directly, and remove the images by hand, on those pages.  This seems a lot of work.  This also is an exact duplicate of an answer already suggest, just more vague, and less helpful.